# python file upload selenium

Tags: python, file, selenium, upload

I use Selenium and Python to send requests to a website. I am making a file upload right now, but it seems that it is not working as I expect it to be.

Here is how to HTML looks like:

```
<div id="uploaders" class="uploaders" data-image-urls="" data-image-ids="" data-image-positions="" data-image-checksums=""><div id="uploader-container-0" class="uploader-container small empty" data-uploader-index="0" data-numbering="1" style="position: relative;">
<div id="file-picker-0" class="uploader-box small" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="uploader-overlay">
            <span class="photo-action edit-action">
                <span class="mp-Icon-circle"><span class="mp-Icon mp-svg-edit photo-action-icon"></span></span>
            </span>
            <span class="remove photo-action">
                <span class="mp-Icon-circle"><span class="mp-Icon mp-svg-delete photo-action-icon"></span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="mp-svg-button-camera camera-logo centered"></div>
        <div class="main-photo-subtext centered">
            Hoofdfoto.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<input type="hidden" name="images.urls" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="images.ids" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="images.checksums" value="">
<div id="html5_1bdvv7bg0ptl15m6gmu1d4v16l04_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;">
<input id="html5_1bdvv7bg0ptl15m6gmu1d4v16l04" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,.jpeg,image/bmp,.bmp,image/png,.png"></div>
```

As you can see in the bottom of the code there is a input type file element. But no form. The file upload on the site works as follows. You click on a (+) sign. Then I file choose dialog box opens, you choose the file. And then there comes another pop-up which asks with a button to click if you want accept something.

My question is how can I upload a file. Till yet I have failed to do this.

My code:

```
upload_photo_field_xpath = ".//*[@id='uploader-container-0']/div/input"
upload_photo_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                                        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(upload_photo_field_xpath))

image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/' + 'img.jpg')
print(image)
upload_photo_element.send_keys(image)
upload_photo_element.submit()
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below step as per your requirement which is working well for me related to upload file

Install win32com.client

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Then include it in your code as below

```
import win32com.client

//click on upload button for uploading file
time.sleep(3)//you can use explicit wait here
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Sendkeys("C:\\Users\\.....\\File.pdf")//file path to be uploaded
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Shoaib Akhtar. I will try this. One question though, is this solution Windows related or can I use this also on Mac.

Comment: Go through this link once 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233461/pywin32-com-objects-on-mac 
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852864/using-python-with-scriptable-applications-on-a-mac

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I just tested this by switching from browser. Instead of using PhantomJS I used Firefox for testing purpose. So I can view what actually is happening behind the scenes. By viewing the browser I came to understand that it needed a couple of seconds to wait in order to handle the file upload handling.

The code:

```
'''Image Upload'''

upload_photo_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(upload_photo_field_ID)
image = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/' + 'img.png')
upload_photo_element.send_keys(image)

# Depending on how long the image takes to load
time.sleep(5)

upload_photo_reject_button_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(upload_photo_reject_button_ID))

upload_photo_reject_button_element.click()

'''End image upload'''
```

This code works for me.

In this way no window will pop-up.

But I noticed also that this works with the Firefox browser, but not with PhantomJS.