# How to handle files uploading by using selenium script?

Tags: selenium

Please help me how to handle upload file and choose file functionality by using Please help me how to handle upload file and choose file functionality by using selenium script.|Please help me how to handle upload file and choose file functionality by using selenium script.|selenium script.|

Comment: You can check my reply here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466268/python-file-upload-selenium/43468017#43468017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask